# Why does creating a course on the Google Classroom API doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-classroom

I'm new to Google APIs and a noob at node.JS.
I can't figure out creating a course doesn't work.

The script for creating a course is a modified version of the apps script example available on the Google Developer website.

Help is highly appriciated as I am a young student trying to make my own e-learning platform based off Google Classroom and other aleardy made solutions.

Am I missing something?

````
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const chalk = require('chalk');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses', 
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Classroom API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listCourses, createCourse);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

function listCourses(auth) {
  const classroom = google.classroom({version: 'v1', auth});
  classroom.courses.list({
    pageSize: 1234,
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error(chalk.red('[ERROR] ') + err);
    const courses = res.data.courses;
    if (courses && courses.length) {
      console.log('Courses:');
      courses.forEach((course) => {
        console.log(`${course.name} (${course.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No courses found.');
    }
  });
}

function createCourse(auth) {
  const classroom = google.classroom({version: 'v1', auth});
  classroom.courses.create({
    name: 'somethin!',
    section: 'Period 2',
    descriptionHeading: 'somethin',
    description: "somethin",
    room: '301',
    ownerId: 'me',
    courseState: 'PROVISIONED',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error(chalk.red('[ERROR] ') + err);
  });
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try separating the call for listCourses and createCourse.

`authorize()` accepts 2 arguments: credentials and callback.

```
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Classroom API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listCourses);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), createCourse);
});
```

I tried to create a course using your request body and it was successful.
[courses.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create)

You might also want to combine your `listCourses()` and `createCourse()` into a single function so that you don't need to get authentication token for each request.

## (UPDATE):

Can you try this:

```
function createCourse(auth) {
  const classroom = google.classroom({version: 'v1', auth});
  classroom.courses.create({
    resource: {
      name: 'somethin!',
      section: 'Period 2',
      descriptionHeading: 'somethin',
      description: "somethin",
      room: '301',
      ownerId: 'me',
      courseState: 'PROVISIONED',
    },
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error(chalk.red('[ERROR] ') + err);
  });
}
```

Due to lack of node.js examples in the Classroom API, I tried to look for other Google API which only sends a request body.

I found this Calendar API [Freebusy.query](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query?hl=en), and based on this [sample node.js code](https://github.com/CamSkiTheDev/Google-Calendar-NodeJS-App/blob/master/index.js), It was called like this:

```
calendar.freebusy.query(
  {
    resource: {
      timeMin: eventStartTime,
      timeMax: eventEndTime,
      timeZone: 'America/Denver',
      items: [{ id: 'primary' }],
    },
  },
  (err, res) => {
    // Check for errors in our query and log them if they exist.
    if (err) return console.error('Free Busy Query Error: ', err) });
```

> request body was set as a resource parameter

Comment: It didn't work. I now get this error: `Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "room": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'room' could not be found in request message.` for each param.

Comment: @thicc, I updated the answer. Can you try if that will work. I can't reproduce your issue since i don't have the required environment. I just tried to look for possible solutions online.

Comment: It worked!! **THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! YOU'RE THE BEST**